# How to push two different directories into a git root

Tags: git, repository, directory

I'm currently working on a website containing two folders at root

```
  .root
     ./backoffice

     ./frontoffice
```

Those two folders are different but need to be on the same level, so they can be accessed directly from the root of the web site (www.mywebsite.com/backoffice or www.mywebsite.com/frontoffice)

I would like to push them to the same git repository, by doing so

- creating a repository mywebsite
- initiating git in this reposity
- adding the repositories /backoffice and /frontoffice in this repository
- pushing everything to my git repo

The problem is that if I make a clone of this repo, I'll get a folder named mywebsite, which contains the two folders I wanted. And I would like having directly my two folders where I decide to do the git clone, how is this possible please ?

Thanks for caring ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could create two git repos rather than one.
That way, you can clone them directly  where you need them.

If you need to group them (in order to remember which version of `backoffice` goes with which version of `frontoffice`), you can create a third repo `mywebsite`, and ad the first two as [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).